# Doxygen call graph: naming convention, using with Sphinx (Breathe)

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

Gurus,

I am documenting C code using doxygen.  I then use Breathe and Sphinx to create my documentation.

- Doxygen v1.9.1
- Sphinx v4.2.0
- breathe v4.30.0
- docutils 0.16 (not upgraded due to issue with bullet list)

**Problem:** Doxygen callgraphs are not being pulled into the final documentation generated by Sphinx/Breathe.

Working correctly:

1. Doxygen generates all callgraphs as requested.
2. The callgraph .dot and .png files are in the html directory.
3. If I view the html source, the callgraph has been inserted into the function documentation.

**What I've tried:**

1. Since Breathe uses xml, I visually checked the doxygen xml output directory and I do not see the call graphs in that directory. I also did a search for png and dot to see if it was embedded in an .xml but didn't find any evidence.
2. A possible workaround: I can include the image png in my reStructuredText by using one of the directives: ..image, or ..figure, or ..graphviz. The name that doxygen gives the files, however, cryptic so I hesitate to do this.   Example: group___b_i_s_s_c_s___s_y_s___i_n_i_t_gac5ed08df903ed0d3f0dfea740ee48d35_cgraph.png

**Question 1:**
*Am I possibly missing a configuration setting to have the call graphs included in the xml as well as the html?*

**Question 2:**
*Any other thing I should check or thoughts on why Breathe isn't picking up the callgraph?*

**Question 3:**
*If I use the filename in my RST, how can I be confident the .png or .dot file name won't change in a future execution of doxygen?*

Comment: Interesting question 1, this part is left for the user of the xml to implement (more freedom) but I can see that it might be convenient to have also the dot images (and possibly other type of images) available and addressable in the xml file. Best to issue an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=report-a-bug-or-issue.md&title=

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I'll post in the doxygen issues.